# Multiple light pixel Shader in GLSL

Tags: opengl, shader

I have wirtten a fragment shader that works just fine with a single light. Now I am trying to adpat it to work with 8 lights, the implement it in Processing. Clearly I am doing something wrong in the math and I cannot see what it is... I have read other posts about this and try to adapt the answer to my problem, no luck though...

[image]

```
////Fragment/////

    #ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
#endif

varying vec4 vertColor;
varying vec3 ecNormal;
varying vec3 lightDir;

void main() {  
  vec3 direction = normalize(lightDir);
  vec3 normal = normalize(ecNormal);
  float intensity = max(0.0, dot(direction, normal));
  gl_FragColor = vec4(intensity, intensity, intensity, 1) * vertColor;
}

////vertex/////

        #define PROCESSING_LIGHT_SHADER

uniform mat4 modelview;
uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

uniform vec4 lightPosition;
uniform vec3 lightNormal;

attribute vec4 vertex;
attribute vec4 color;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying vec4 vertColor;
varying vec3 ecNormal;
varying vec3 lightDir;

void main() {
  gl_Position = transform * vertex;    
  vec3 ecVertex = vec3(modelview * vertex);  

  ecNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
  lightDir = normalize(lightPosition.xyz - ecVertex);  
  vertColor = color;
}
```

Comment: show us what your output is and describe what you expect it to be

Comment: It just wont compile. It is a version of a basic pixel ilumination shader. The previous version just supports 1 light. I am trying to adapt it so that it can process 8 lights.

Comment: we'll need to see the info log from the failed compilation/linking. It's a good practice to always log it while developing.

Comment: I am pretty much just starting with shaders...  I do get :


 
Cannot compile frgament shader: 0(24) : error C1101: ambiguous overloaded function reference "mul(mat4, vec3") (0): mat3x4 mul(mat3x1, mat1x4) (0): mat3 mul(mat3x1, mat1x3) (0): mat3x2 mul(mat3x1, mat1x2) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message the problem is in line 24 of your fragment shader:

```
vec3 transformedNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
```

`normalMatrix` is a `mat4` but `normal` is a `vec3`.

The solution is to make normalMatrix a mat3 instead.

Comment: I do not get matrix errors anymore but It just wont compile. I have posted the original working code for a single light. How should I approach it?